# Finding the Probability of B, knowing the Probability of B | A and B|A'

Tags: probability

For a Problem with Events A and B, I know:

$P(A)$, $P(B|A)$, and $P(B|A')$

This has come up in a a couple different problems in my homework, and the provided solution always involves the following equality:

$$P(B)=P(A)*P(B|A)+P(A')*P(B|A')$$

I can't figure out how to derive this relationship from the Probability Rules/Axioms and Bay's Theorem. Could someone provide the steps that prove the above statement?

Comment: This is the law of total probability,

Comment: For future reference, that statement is the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, $$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A')$$

Because $A,A'$ exhaust the universe without duplication.

Second:  $$P(B\cap A)=P(A)P(B|A)$$ by the definition of conditional probability.

Similarly: $$P(B\cap A')=P(A')P(B|A')$$

The conclusion follows by substitution.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed. Much thanks!